# Why height property does not work on this div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a website with HTML and CSS. I just want a lot of div side by side.

This is my code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.box {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Scroll Animation</h1>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

when I change the height of `box` class, it does not work, but when I change the width property, it works. I change the `flex-direction`, the height property also does not work.

What is the problem? How can I get the height which I want? Please help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try adding `flex-shink: 0;` to `.box`? Prevent the boxes from shrinking

Comment: Add `flex-shrink: 0;` to `.box`es

Answer (score 3):

You set the `body` element to `display: flex` and `height: 100vh` so the boxes are laid out using flex layout within a constrained height.

By default, `flex-shrink` is `1` so they shrink to fit.

You need to change the shrink rule to `0` if you want the height you specified for the boxes to take priority over the space available for them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.box {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Scroll Animation</h1>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

… or remove the restriction on the body height so they don't need to shrink to fit the space you allocated for them.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.box {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Scroll Animation</h1>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `flex-direction: row` *(default)*, items will be aligned horizontally.
To adjust horizontal space for items in this mode you should use `flex-basis`, `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` e.g `flex:1;` and use height in the normal manner,

When you are using `flex-direction: column` the items will be aligned vertically. When items are "rotated" vertically, `flex-basis`, `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` will now affect the vertical space "height" and height property will now affect the horizontal space "width" of the items.

### EXAMPLE

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex:0 0 200px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: steelblue;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Scroll Animation</h1>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

in the block, the height of the case is 100vh and due to the display flex limits the maximum height, removing it, you can increase the height arbitrarily. and generally better to write max-height: 2000px; height: 100%;

Comment: This doesn't help in this scenario.